# How to detect missing payment in timeseries?

Tags: r, time-series

I have a dataframe with monthly automatic payments of company X and Y, see dataframe.

The exact dates can differ a bit due to the weekends, thus not each payment will be on the exact same day of the month for example.

What is more important is that approximately each 30-34 days a payment has to be fulfilled by each company. The first payment date of company X is 2020-03-01, and the first payment date of company Y is 2020-03-10.

```
dat1 <- data.frame(
  booked_at = c("2020-03-01", "2020-03-10", "2020-04-02", "2020-04-10", "2020-05-02", "2020-06-10", 
                "2020-07-02", "2020-07-10", "2020-08-02", "2020-09-09", "2020-10-02", "2020-10-10"),
  amount    = rep.int(c(100, 150), 6),
  company   = c("X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "Y")
)

dat1

#     booked_at amount company
# 1  2020-03-01    100       X
# 2  2020-03-10    150       Y
# 3  2020-04-02    100       X
# 4  2020-04-10    150       Y
# 5  2020-05-02    100       X
# 6  2020-06-10    150       Y
# 7  2020-07-02    100       X
# 8  2020-07-10    150       Y
# 9  2020-08-02    100       X
# 10 2020-09-09    150       Y
# 11 2020-10-02    100       X
# 12 2020-10-10    150       Y
```

As you can see, some payments are missing (e.g. "2020-06-02" and "2020-09-02" for company X and
"2020-05-10" and "2020-08-10" for company Y).

What I would like to create is a function that counts the missing payment dates. Thus, a new dataframe should expose those dates where a payment is missing, if possible.

The final output of the function should show a dataframe with the company name and missing payment dates

Comment: So the dates are not exactly 1 month apart? It could be anything between 30-34 days? Also can you have missing payment dates for more than 1 month i.e for 3-4 months?

Comment: No, the dates are not exactly 1 month apart from each other all the time, this is due to weekend days. And yes, missing payment dates can be more than 1 month in a row, e.g. 2 months of missing payments after each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If by any chance, company can have advance payments too, usage of `round_date` instead of `floor_date` is suggested.**

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
dat1 %>% group_by(company) %>% mutate(booked_at2 = floor_date(as.Date(booked_at), unit = "month")) %>%
  complete(booked_at2 = seq.Date(min(booked_at2), max(booked_at2), by = "month"))

# A tibble: 16 x 4
# Groups:   company [2]
   company booked_at2 booked_at  amount
   <chr>   <date>     <chr>       <dbl>
 1 X       2020-03-01 2020-03-01    100
 2 X       2020-04-01 2020-04-02    100
 3 X       2020-05-01 2020-05-02    100
 4 X       2020-06-01 NA             NA
 5 X       2020-07-01 2020-07-02    100
 6 X       2020-08-01 2020-08-02    100
 7 X       2020-09-01 NA             NA
 8 X       2020-10-01 2020-10-02    100
 9 Y       2020-03-01 2020-03-10    150
10 Y       2020-04-01 2020-04-10    150
11 Y       2020-05-01 NA             NA
12 Y       2020-06-01 2020-06-10    150
13 Y       2020-07-01 2020-07-10    150
14 Y       2020-08-01 NA             NA
15 Y       2020-09-01 2020-09-09    150
16 Y       2020-10-01 2020-10-10    150
```

you can removed additional column easily, if not required.

Comment: Yeah this works, and then using this dataframe I can easily filter the NA booked_at dates per company, thanks!

Comment: Oh I thought you needed complete info otherwise I would've filtered these too.  Glad that it helped. :)

Comment: By the way, if you need to filter out rows only you may mutate `booked_at` column directly instead of creating another col

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Convert to a zoo series with yearmon index (year and month without day) splitting by company so that the rows are year/months and the columns are companies.  Then convert that to a ts series and back to zoo to fill in any entirely missing months.  Then lapply over the columns returning a vector of year/months that are NAs for each one.

```
library(zoo)

z <- as.zoo(as.ts(read.zoo(dat1, FUN = as.yearmon, split = "company")))
lapply(as.data.frame(z), function(x) time(z)[is.na(x)])
```

giving this named list of yearmon vectors:

```
$X
[1] "Jun 2020" "Sep 2020"

$Y
[1] "May 2020" "Aug 2020"
```

**2)** Alternately using z from above use `which` to get the indices of the NA's in z and create a data frame `out` from that and optionally sort it.

```
wx <- which(is.na(z), arr = TRUE)
out <- data.frame(yearmon = time(z)[wx[, 1]], company = colnames(z)[wx[, 2]])
out[with(out, order(yearmon, company)), ] # optional
```

giving:

```
     Index company
1 May 2020       Y
2 Jun 2020       X
3 Aug 2020       Y
4 Sep 2020       X
```

**3)** Another possible output is to subset to those rows of z that have an NA

```
subset(z, is.na(rowSums(z)))
```

giving t his zoo object (or use fortify.zoo(...) on that to get a data frame:

```
           X   Y
May 2020 100  NA
Jun 2020  NA 150
Aug 2020 100  NA
Sep 2020  NA 150
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)   

dat1 %>% filter(company=='X') -> x_company
dat1 %>% filter(company=='Y') -> y_company

x_company$booked_at[1] -> first_date_x
x_company$booked_at[length(x_company$booked_at)] -> last_date_x
seq.Date(as.Date(first_date_x),as.Date(last_date_x),by = 'month') %>% as.data.frame -> check 
names(check) <- 'check'
check <- check %>% mutate(check_month=month(check))
x_company <- x_company %>% mutate(booked_at=as.Date(booked_at)) %>% mutate(month=month(booked_at))

check %>% left_join(x_company,by=c('check_month'='month')) %>%
mutate(company=ifelse(is.na(company),'X',company)) -> x_new

y_company$booked_at[1] -> first_date_y
y_company$booked_at[length(y_company$booked_at)] -> last_date_y
seq.Date(as.Date(first_date_y),as.Date(last_date_y),by = 'month') %>% as.data.frame -> check 
names(check) <- 'check'
check <- check %>% mutate(check_month=month(check))
y_company <- y_company %>% mutate(booked_at=as.Date(booked_at)) %>% mutate(month=month(booked_at))

check %>% left_join(y_company,by=c('check_month'='month'))%>%
mutate(company=ifelse(is.na(company),'Y',company)) -> y_new

new <- rbind(x_new,y_new) %>% 
mutate(date=ifelse(is.na(booked_at),check,booked_at),date=as.Date(date,origin = '1970-01-01')) %>% 
select(date,amount,company) %>% rename(booked_at=date) %>% arrange(booked_at)

new
```

the output will look like this;

[image]

Comment: Nice, this would be a good start! However, beforehand I don't exactly know how many companies there are in the dataframe. For example, there could be 2 companies (like in this example), or there could be 3, 4, 5 or more companies in the dataframe. Therefore, filtering on a specific company is not possible

Comment: @WenkyWong you gotta know when each started to pay and the last date they paid then create a sequence from them by month, you can extract month from original then join the sequence. non match months will be NA. I may not be clear, it needs some creativity insight here.